# How do I give external or local html doc link to bootstrap nav-pills?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to link my another webpage to my pictures nav menu.
Ex: if I click my pictures menu , it opens google.com.

Framework: bootstrap 4

```
div class="row row2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center nav-justified" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#">About me</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#">My pictures</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#">My music</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#">My files</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#">My videos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Racil Hilan but,I need data-toggle to show the pills on the tab.

Comment: No,I want to link all 5 nav menu to some links then what can I do??

Comment: If I remove data-toggle it's  working . But,pills not working.

Answer (score 1):

This will work  :)

```
<div class="row row2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center nav-justified" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#">About me</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" target="_blank" href="http://google.com">My pictures</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#">My music</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#">My files</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#">My videos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks it working.
I added _self to open in same tab.

Comment: can you provide any link or fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code for my question. i solve this with your help. thankyou

**Html**

```
<div class="row row2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center nav-justified" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about_me.html">About me</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="my_pictures.html">My pictures</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="my_music.html">My music</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="my_files.html">My files</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="my_videos.html">My videos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .active {
    background-color: #39a0c9 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```